# Can't import file in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I am trying to import the "views" file. this doesn't work-> "from . import views". It gives this error->ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
When I use "import views" it gives " Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You
must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings." this error.
All the files are in the same place.

Comment: I believe that it is required in the installed apps variable to place your apps of the project.

Answer (score 0):

where are you importing the file from? have you correctly configured your setting.py? what is your files structure?
we need more info to understand the problem

EDIT: you could use

```
from .views import about, anasayfa

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('', anasayfa, name='anasayfa'),

]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just tried that and it gave "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package" error I am now trying to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while using Django it PyCharm. But I was able to solve the problem using the following steps :-
(basically what I did was adding project paths to the interpreter in virtual-env).

Step 1: Go to Interpreter Settings

[image: Go to Interpreter Settings]

Step 2: Go to Show All

[image: Go to Show All]

Step 3: Click on Interpreter Paths

[image: Click on Interpreter Paths]

Step 4: Now click on the + button to add the path to your project folder, app folder and others as well.

Step 5: After that Save and Apply.

Step 6: Now close the Project and Reopen the Project.

Hope it Works.